# ORDER BY id DESC

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I simply want to ORDER the comments by the ID, but I have no luck in doing it. Can't figure out what to do, because this is confusing me: `articleid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'`

Would you guys happen to know how I could go about ordering the comments by the id in DESC? thanks!

```
<?php

$amount_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE articleid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'"); $comments = mysql_num_rows($amount_get);

$grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE articleid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'");


if (mysql_num_rows($grab)==0) {

    echo "<div class='alert alert-note-x'>Sorry, it looks like their are no comments to be displayed, check back later!</div>";
}

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($grab)){

    ?>
```

Comment: What is the field name of the comment's id?

Comment: Sorry for off-topic, but please read red box: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @TaylordKris: "bear".  Like the furry critter.  Not "bare" (like "no clothes").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you're doing the same `SELECT` two times. That's pretty unnecessary since you can count rows and get the data from a single query. Additionally to this replace `commentid` with the unique id of your comment table and you're set. Replace `DESC` with `ASC` to reverse the sort order.

```
<?php
    $grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE articleid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "' ORDER BY commentid DESC");
    $comments = mysql_num_rows($grab);

    if (mysql_num_rows($grab)==0) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-note-x'>Sorry, it looks like their are no comments to be displayed, check back later!</div>";
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($grab)){

?>
```

Comment: See I tried that before, but it didn't work. Probably because as you said, I had SELECT 2 times. But now it works perfectly. Thank you! and to everyone else who helped.. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

add `ORDER BY` clause

```
$grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE articleid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "' ORDER BY articleid, ID DESC");
```

your query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please read the article below to protect from it,

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: This code won't work since all the comments have the same articleid.

Comment: The parameter in the query is escaped and wrapped with single quotes, other than using BIG-5 encoding or anything else obscure wouldn't make it vulnerable against an injection, would it?

Comment: You should use mysqli_ instead of mysql_ extension.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE articleid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "' order by articleid desc");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your comments table habe a column `id` then, so:

```
$grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE articleid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

This is a sql thing to sort it, not php, so you just have to modify your sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$amount_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE articleid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "' ORDER BY id DESC "); 

$grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE articleid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions:

1) Complete your "select" statement in a string variable (as shown below; it makes debugging much easier)

2) Consider using prepared statements instead of raw "select" (or update or delete!).

It can help performance.  But it makes your PHP *much* more secure!

3) Consider moving away from the (deprecated) mysql_query() syntax

```
<?php

  $sql = 
    "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE articleid='" . 
    mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "' order by articleid desc";
  $amount_get = mysql_query($sql); 
  $comments = mysql_num_rows($amount_get);

  $sql = 
    "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE articleid='" . 
    mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'order by articleid desc";
  $grab = mysql_query($sql);
  ...
```

Here's a good link on the mySQLi and PDI APIs that supercede the old mysql_query() syntax:

- [mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

And here's a good link on prepared statements:

- http://forum.codecall.net/topic/44392-php-5-mysqli-prepared-statements/#axzz2Dazi7pQ4

Answer (score 0):

You can use order by clause in your query

```
    <?php
$getarticles = array();
$getarticles = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment order by articleid desc");

if(empty($getarticles)){
echo "<div class='alert alert-note-x'>Sorry, it looks like their are no comments to be displayed, check back later!</div>";
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($getarticles);
echo "</pre>";

    for($i=0;$i<count($getarticles);$i++){
//display
}

    ?>
```