# using ORDER BY id DESC and where

Tags: php, mysql

how can i use right code for using `ORDER BY id DESC and WHERE`

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM items where portfolio_id=".$_GET['folio_id']."ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: Try adding space  before `ORDER BY`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Without sounding rude, this question could have been avoided with a little patience and research. If you haven't managed to find the problem after hours of debugging, a quick Google search **"mysql where order by"** would have yielded hundreds of examples, tutorials and explanations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620961/order-by-id-desc?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Add a space here as shown.

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM items where portfolio_id=".$_GET['folio_id']." ORDER BY id DESC";
                                                                ----^
```

Also, don't pass your parameters like `$_GET` or `$_POST` directly into the SQL query as it will definitely lead to SQL Injection Attacks. Filter those parameters or make use of **`Prepared Statements`**.

Comment: Cannot see a reason for the down-votes. In all fairness, it should be getting up-voted, as it's the only answer that has warned against injection attacks and suggests the use of prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

add a space before 'ORDER' at least

```
 $sel = "SELECT * FROM items where portfolio_id=".$_GET['folio_id']." ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need provide space before `ORDER BY`

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM items where portfolio_id=".$_GET['folio_id']." ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use this :

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM items where portfolio_id ='$_GET[folio_id]' ORDER BY id DESC";
```